‘Block Secrets on Push’ Feature Not Working as Expected
I’m encountering an issue with the “Block secrets on push” feature in Azure DevOps (ADO). Despite having the checkbox checked under **Settings **> Advanced Security, I was able to push a secret to the repository and submit a pull request without any blocks.
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?
Thanks!
Steps to Reproduce:

Navigate to Settings > Advanced Security in the ADO repository.
Verify that the “Block secrets on push” feature is enabled.
Add a secret to the code.
Push the changes to the repository.
Create a pull request with the changes.


Hi @Louis XIV, Welcome to SO. May I know if Advanced Security was recently enabled for your repository? Were you able to see the secret scanning alerts from the Advance Security section of your repo or you could observe it was initializing the scan? For another direction to narrow down the issue, if possible, would you create a PAT of your Azure DevOps account and push it to a new repo? Please don't forget to revoke the PAT after the test.

Thanks Alvin.

Yes, Advanced Security was recently enabled for the repository.
I see it in the secrets list in the Advanced Security / Secrets page (alerts?_t=secrets)

I am not sure what you mean by pushing a PAT to a new repo. Can you please elaborate?

Your refer to this document to test to create and push a Personal Access Token. Don't forget to revoke it after the test. By the way, you were trying to push a secret value in Azure Repos Web UI or IDE?

Hi Alvin,
I was able to push a commit containing a SAS token - it should be treated similarly to a PAT.
I am not sure what is meant by "Azure Repos Web UI or IDE"?
I tried both a git push command, as well as the Visual Studio UI.

Hi Louis, I also generated a SAS token of my storage account and tried to push the commit with it into my repo, but failed with the error saying VS403654: The push was rejected because it contains one or more secrets. Resolve the following secrets before pushing again. For help, see https://aka.ms/advancedsecurity/secret-scanning/push-protection. Secrets: commit: 2ac047754c90896e4ff6fb0c482d70d0b5d5fc18 paths: /README.md(4,108-158) : SEC101/149 : AzureStorageSa. I suspected if the remote repo url configured in you local repo was not that Azure Repo enabled with GHAS.

To rule out this mismatch, we could have a test to Edit any test file in the Azure Repo web UI. You may navigate to https://dev.azure.com/<YourADOOrgName>/<TheProjectName>/_git/<AzureRepoName> -> Click on the more options button of any test file to Edit with a secret value like SAS. If you are able to push it and see the alert regarding this commit, it can probably require the engineering team to be engaged. You can modify your original post with some screenshots as updates. Please don't forget to scrub and revoke those test secrets for test. Thx.

In addtion, For tokens such as Azure Storage Keys, Advanced Security only supports recently created tokens, not tokens that match the legacy patterns. Would you also test to create a new SAS and push it to Azure Repo for a test?

Hi Alvin.
I see what is happening. Changing one character in the SAS token was enough for the tool to deem it as not a secret.
With a real secret, the push was reject as expected.
Thanks for all your help!

Hi Louis, Many thx your efforts and taking time to update the finding that the block secret push functionality works for a valid SAS token. Good luck with your works to go and cheers!

Hi @LouisXIV, Glad to know the query is resolved. Would consider this to help others with similar concerns. Thanks again for the sharing.

Based on our further investigations, we observed that modifying a single character in the SAS token caused the tool to classify it as non-sensitive. However, when a valid secret was used, the push was correctly rejected, as expected.
Additionally, it is important to highlight the following:

Push protection may not block older versions of certain tokens as these tokens may generate a higher number of false positives than their most recent version. Push protection may also not block legacy tokens. For tokens such as Azure Storage Keys, Advanced Security only supports recently created tokens, not tokens that match the legacy patterns.

For more detailed information, please refer to the official documentation on Secret Scanning for GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn.
